# MDA (Model Driven Architecture)

Tags: database, mda

I have a doubt about MDA.

And this is my doubt, 
I can used the MDA concepts in a architecture that is not related to it(e.g ER), ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. MDA is just a set of guidelines that you can follow in any "modeling stack" you're using.

It's true that MDA is OMG's vision of Model-driven development (see [my simple view on the differences between MDA and related acronyms like MDE, MDD,](https://modeling-languages.com/clarifying-concepts-mbe-vs-mde-vs-mdd-vs-mda/)...) and therefore many people following MDA principles stick to OMG languages like UML but this is by no means mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Any architecture is based on some model, even if this model is not explicitly presented. That is where MDA helps to realize that and gives means to use.